# Converting from jsonschema to swagger 2.0

Tags: jsonschema, swagger-2.0

New to swagger and would like to know if there is a way to convert and existing jsonschema model to swagger specification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to JSON Schema draft 4 compatible with Swagger 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908214/convert-json-to-json-schema-draft-4-compatible-with-swagger-2-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a Swagger #definition from sample JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277137/how-to-generate-a-swagger-definition-from-sample-json)